# How to extract only the selected information from the form using javascript and create a dictionary based on keys and values?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a form that is generated dynamically based on the tool's parameters. In the form sub-section being shown or hidden based on the selected options. I am trying to collect the data from the user input, and I want to create a dictionary for the visible or selected sections.

```
<form class="tool-form">
<button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-4">
   <label class="custom_file_upload">
      <input type="file"><input type="text" name="infile" list="car">
      <datalist id="car">
         <option>Volvo</option>
         <option>Suzuki</option>
      </datalist>
      <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"> Upload Data</i>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-5">
   <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Peptide Column</span></div>
   <input id="input-uid-5" name="peps">
</div>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-6">
   <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Method to convert data</span></div>
   <select name="method" id="select-uid-6">
      <option value="0"> Convert Without Split </option>
      <option value="1">Split Data By Class Label</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2 " id="uid-6-section-0" style="display: block;">
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-8">
      <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Column with the class label</span></div>
      <input id="input-uid-8" name="classlabel">
   </div>
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-10">
      <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Peptide ID Column</span></div>
      <select name="columnselect" id="select-uid-10">
         <option value="0"> Add Peptide ID Column Name </option>
         <option value="1"> No Peptide ID Column </option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2 " id="uid-10-section-0" style="display: block;">
      <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-12">
         <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Column name with peptide IDs</span></div>
         <input id="input-uid-12" name="clmname">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2 " id="uid-10-section-1" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2 " id="uid-6-section-1" style="display: none;">
<div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-14">
   <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Column name with peptide IDs</span></div>
   <select name="columnselect" id="select-uid-14">
      <option value="0"> Add Peptide ID Column Name </option>
      <option value="1"> No Peptide ID Column </option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2 " id="uid-14-section-0" style="display: block;">
<div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-16">
   <div class="ui-from-title"><span class="ui-form-title-text" style="display: inline;">Select Peptide ID Column</span></div>
   <input id="input-uid-16" name="clmname">
</div>
```

I tried to create a function like this but it does not work the way I want it to work;

```
    const getFormData = () => {
        const form = self.el.querySelector(".Galaxy-form");
        return new FormData(form);
      }
      
      const toJson = function(event) {
        const formData = getFormData();
        event.preventDefault();
        let object = {};
        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
          if (!Reflect.has(object, key)) {
            object[key] = value;
            return;
          }
          if (!Array.isArray(object[key])) {
            object[key] = [object[key]];
          }
          object[key].push(value);
        });
        let json = JSON.stringify(object);
        console.log(json);
      };
      
      Button.addEventListener("click", toJson);
```

I don't want to use Jquery for this how can I achieve this with the only JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: what is `Button` in `Button.addEventListener("click", toJson);`

Comment: why your `submit` button in the form is `style="display: none;"`?

Comment: I have another button that I use to trigger this button and some other functions, But I updated the code.